# The definition of 'familiarity' in the English Liguistics

Tags: definite-article

My understanding of ‘familiarity’ according to the theories of Christophersen, Karttunen, and Heim is that it does not embrace those referents interpreted under ‘accommodation,’ ‘inferrability,’ or ‘bridging.’ Is my understanding correct?

*I went into the class and talked to **the teacher**.* [***the teacher***: its existence is accommodated]

This referent is not regarded as ‘familiar’ to the hearer at the time of utterance even though he/she can accommodate it?

I always become so confused when I hear the word 'familiar' in the discussion of the definite article. I wonder to what extent 'familiarity' embraces definite NP's? Are accommodated referents 'familiar'? Are the weak definite nouns 'familiar' (In a room with three equally salient windows. "It's hot in here. Could you open ***the window***?") ?

Comment: Could you please cite the work (or the works) which you are referring to? It's very hard to understand your question.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/321065/definition-of-familiarity-in-the-english-linguistics

Comment: You might consider removing both questions, and then re-posting your question on [Linguistics.SE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) with more details and specific references to the papers by each author that you've read and are having trouble with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [linguistics.se]

Comment: FWIW, from a paper by Barbara Abbott, *[Definite and Indefinite](https://msu.edu/~abbottb/def&inde.pdf)*: "In Christophersen’s view [of "familiarity"], what distinguishes definite from indefinite descriptions is whether or not the addressee of the utterance is presumed to be acquainted with the referent of the NP. In an often cited passage, Christophersen remarks: “Now the speaker must always be supposed to know which individual he is thinking of; the interesting thing is that the *the*-form supposes that the hearer knows it too” (Christophersen 1939, 28)."

Comment: Familiarity is a (badly chosen) technical word here. When Heim uses this term it just means that it's already been mentioned in the discourse/conversation. It doesn't mean familiar in any other way. Your quite right that *familiar* in its normal meaning would also apply to, for example *the moon*, but not in Heim's sense (I don't think, but I'm no expert ) ...

Answer (score 1):

When one says *the X*, the speaker is communicating that he/she expects the listener to know *which* X for various reasons.

Those reasons include:

- Speaker and listener have directly observed that particular X.
- Speaker has talked about that particular X previously in a conversation with the listener.
- There is only one X possible in the current context and it would affect anyone in that context.  *The sky* is an example.
- X describes something that is considered "directly observable by default."

One thing that makes this complicated to anaylze is that the speaker may be making an understood jump back in the context and is expecting the listener to follow it.

> A: Why are you sad?
>
> B: I just broke up with my girlfriend.
>
> A: That's terrible.  Are you OK?
>
> B: I don't know.  The feelings I had for her were strong.

B is expecting A to know which "feelings" he is talking about, so *the* is used - because the context is them talking about a break up and therefore love and therefore feelings is involved.

In your example:

> "It's hot in here. Could you open the window?"

we can draw the conclusion from the use of *the* that the speaker and listener are working in a familiar place with windows they have seen before, and there is a particular single window known to the speaker and within reach of the listener.  The speaker is expecting the listener to know which window.

Whereas:

> "It's hot in here. Could you open a window?"

The speaker doesn't care which window is opened OR the speaker isn't actually able to see where the listener is to "fix" which window.

One thing to keep in mind is that the jump back in context can be very short, as short as simply earlier in the sentence.

> I went into the class and talked to the teacher.

*The class* is something the speaker expects the listener to know about outside of the sentence.  But *the teacher* could be linked back to the small context created in the same sentence by "I went into the class".  Essentially implying the speaker went into the class and talked to the teacher *of* that class.

However, it is also possible the speaker is talking about a teacher previously mentioned outside of the sentence and that he/she is merely talking to a teacher *in* the class (who may not be the teacher of that class).  There could be an ambiguity but previous sentences/conversation would likely have cleared that up.

Comment: The point about "could you open the window" is misleading, I believe. [See our chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29203071#29203071).

Comment: @CowperKettle I don't think the point is misleading and I don't think this post deserves a downvote. It is one of a few possible scenarios.

Comment: @CowperK - Let's say you and I are working in a hot room with three windows along one wall. You are between me and the middle window. I might easily say, "Could you open the window?" and you might reply "Sure," and proceed to open any one of the three. (I might be surprised if you stepped to your left and opened a different one, and I may or may not be bothered that the one you opened isn't the one I expected you to open, but the lines between specificity and inference can be blurry.) That's an interesting chat between you and Snail, but I don't see how it invalidates this answer.